# Why this sentence used "with" instead of "of"

Tags: prepositions

I came across a sentence, which used *with* instead of *of*, and it goes like this:

> "You may lose the contest due to the weight disadvantage **with** your dogs".

Can you explain the case here, is the usage of "with" here right, or can I use "of" to replace "With", and which one sounds more natural in your native speakers' ears! Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: *With* means accompanying; *of* means belonging to or associated.  In either case the sentence means that a weight disadvantage will obtain with this choice of dogs.  They both sound fine to me.  (The prepositions, not the dogs)

Comment: No, it doesn't seem right.  But I'm not sure what the sentence is trying to say in general so it is hard to say what might be better.  ...  Oh I see what it's trying to say now.  How 'bout: *You may lose the contest due to the weight disadvantage your dogs will have [against their opponents]*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Of" may show a common Quality of that dog...part of it...which it have all times.
"problem with you"..."disadvantage"  is temporary...
It may Change...

Answer (score 0):

Using "of" gives a nuance or emphasis that the weight problem belongs to your dogs. However, "you" are competing in the contest, so using "with" is appropriate in this sentence: "You have a problem with X" is normal structure. You can have a problem WITH your car, but in this sentence your problem is WITH or "related to" your dogs' weight.